# how do I disable new user registration email for specific admin user?

Tags: configuration

As the title of the question says, I would like only specific admin users to receive the new registration emails. Is it possible to restrict which admin user receives it?

Currently all admin users will receive an email notification.

I don't want to disable it globally but only on a per user basis.

Answer (score 1):

Going by wordpress `wp_new_user_notification`, [github](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/35aaaacc044c12e1b4c4a3cd3b90578a7e79a65e/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L2006), [wordpress code reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_new_user_notification/), the function that handles sending email for new users, it only send email to user and site admin by default.

There's a filter `wp_new_user_notification_email_admin` that you can hook into to change the admin details, maybe you have a plugin that uses this filter.

Try disabling them one by one and see if it fixes it.